# Как заполнить массив в цикле?

Tags: php, массивы

Есть цикл:

```
foreach($json as $el) {
echo $el['name'].' / '.$el['quantity']. PHP_EOL;    
}
```

в результате 2х выполнений цикла выводится:

```
Шарики для роликов / 2
Коньки / 3
```

Мне нужно написать цикл таким образом, чтобы после завершения цикла, на выходе была создана перменная
$mass, значение которой было:

```
$mass=array(array('quantity' =>  2,'offer' => array('id' => 'шарики')),array('quantity' =>  3,'offer' => array('id' => 'коньки')),);
```

Как вы поняли в этой массиве подставляются только 2 переменные

```
$el['name']
$el['quantity']
```

Два раза, по кол-ву выполнений цикла.

Цикл может быть выполнен и 10 раз. нужно предусмотреть.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$_POST='{"sys":"none","systranid":"0","orderid":"1987774240","products":[{"name":"Шарики для роликов","quantity":"2","amount":"2000","price":"1000","sku":"00-00003462"},{"name":"Коньки","quantity":"3","amount":"6000","price":"2000","sku":"00-00003463"}],"amount":"8000"}';

$json=json_decode($_POST,true)['products'];
$out=array_map( function($v){ return ['quantity'=>$v['quantity'], 'offer'=>['id'=>$v['name']]]; }, $json);

print_r($out);
```